# Bootstrap get priority over my CSS - with correct implementation order

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've linked bootstrap's css file first.
I've linked my css file second.

[image: css implementation order]

Why does bootstrap gets priority over my css??
I've played with the file order, there is no "important" setting on the bs rules.
I haven't found any related issue... please help. thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this situation, bootstrap's code is more specific (has 2 classes, while yours has only one specified).

Take a look at [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for more information

You can override bootstrap by being more specific or using '!important' in your css rule (be aware that usually !important is not to be preferred, higher specificity is more flexible and easy to further override or change)

`color: #C77358 !important;`

Comment: Yes, I've solved it by specifying the exact same way bs did: .navbar-dark .navbar-brand.
Thank you.

Comment: I generally don't like using !important. Only when it absolutely necessary. So I'd had to find another way to solve it. it's the first time I'm using a bs component. usually only using the grid layout. learn something new every day. Thanks again.

Comment: In fact, using !important is usually bad habit, I may update my answer including this information

Comment: Having to add `!important` after every property seems dirty. Any way to mark whole class as important ?

Comment: @Yusuf Indeed it is, and !important is not supported for the whole class. Like stated in the answer, higher specificity has to be preferred. If you want to override a class, increase the number of selectors used in the rule declaration (ids and classes are better than plain elements names). i.e. ".btn" --> "body.page #main-container .btn". The linked MDN page explains this in details.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding another class to the navbar element, and styling it in your css file instead of using `.navbar-brand`.

Comment: Thanks. Actually that was the first thing I tried. but it didn't take. 
I found the solution just after posting the question... posting the answer just about now.

Answer (score 0):

when you create your custom css use id instead of class becuse id has more priority then class
so bootstrap use class and you use id then your custom css has more priority then bootstrap class

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).